# Understanding the use of a temporary object

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

Maybe a stupid question but I thought I'll ask it anyway since I am still trying to wrap my head around memory management.

Is this :

1.

```
ViewController *tViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.viewController = tViewController;
[tViewController release];
```

better than this :

2.

```
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

How and why?

**EDIT:**

Ok, in the first instance, I have safely released whatever I have owned. I can see that happening.

But in the second case, it is a deferred release, so how do I figure out when it is gone? This `autorelease` stuff kind of confuses me.

This is not the only instance in a program where such a thing might happen. When I want a particular object I have created to stay alive till god knows when, what do I do? I `autorelease` it? But if it goes away at the wrong time? What do I do then?

Comment: why don't you use ARC?

Comment: To use ARC effectively later, I want to learn Manual Memory Management first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always said in my books, that the second way is the better one. But in the past some people disagreed, esp. on iOS. What's the difference?

1. Is there any difference?

Both variants allocates an object. Both variants take care of releasing it. ("Autorelease is a release.") But they do it at different points in time:

1. Variant: The object is released at the end of the ARP, at least at the end of the runloop.
2. Variant 2: The object is released immediatly with `release`.

(Both: If there is no additional reference.)

1. Why do I need -autorelease?

There are situations, in which a `release` is not possible without breaking the MM rules. The easiest case is that you want to return an allocated object. Who should release it? The creating method? This would return something potentially deallocated. The method, that sent the message? This would unbalance +1 methods like `alloc` with -1 methods like `release`. No way out.

Example:

```
- (NSString*)fullName
{
   NSString *fullName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@, %@", self.lastName, self.firstName];
   return fullName; // Who balance +alloc?
}
```

By autoreleasing the object, your method stays balanced and can safely return the object.

In other cases it is a convenient way to get rid of dependencies. Imagine this code:

```
Person *person = …;
NSString *name = person.name;
[person release], person=nil; // Imagine that this will dealloc the instance.
// name is invalid, because person released it.
```

With `autorelease` you do not have that problem. There are several solutions:

The getter sends `retain`, `autorelease` to the return value. There is an additional reference in the ARP preventig the string from dealloction:

```
- (NSString*)name
{ return [[_name retain] autorelease]; }
```

Or the one, who uses the method does it:

```
NSString *name = [[person.name retain] autorelease];
```

The next problem with problem with `release` is, that it is more difficult to use `return`, `break` or `continue`:

```
while (…)
{
    id object = [[Class alloc] …]
    if (…)
    {
       break;
    }
    [object release];
}
```

There is no problem with autorelease.

Next: For some reasons it is a good idea to use convenience allocators, if exist. Objects returned from there are not allowed to be released explicitly, so the code for given up a reference has a dependency on how the reference was set. Why not using autorelease the whole time?

1. What is the disadvantage of autorelease

The object deletion is potentially deferred so you can get problems with the memory footprint. But I personally think, that `@autorelease{}` is a better solution for that than `release`.

Comment: Convenience allocators? Example?

Comment: I guess the first part of your answer was something I required because you were hitting the "why autorelease?" part of my question. The `retain` was especially important. So, I'll give it to you.

Comment: @BlackFlam3 First of all: Thanks.

Comment: @BlackFlam3 Convencience allocators have the form +class… like +string… (NSString), for example +stringWithString:. It is better to use them instead of +alloc-init (and -autorelease), because sometimes classes want to allocate instances of special subclasses depending on the arguments passed to -init… So +alloc cannot know, which subclass to instantiate. -init… reinstantiates (or do some other trick) a newly allocated instance. More complicated than +class…

Answer (score 3):

The end result is the same in both but the way they get there is different. In both cases you are creating a temporary reference that gets released later.

The first version releases the instance immediately on the release (deterministic) - although since self.viewController is probably a strong reference the instance will not be deallocated on the release call.

The second version releases the instance at some point in the future (non-deterministic) when the current autorelease pool is deallocated. Again - if self.viewController is holding a reference against it won't be deallocated then.

Comment: (+1) I only would replace "temporary instance" by "temporary reference" in the first sentence.

Comment: Additional note: The only advantage of the second method is that you can write it in one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Both does the same .The only difference is 1 has a reference[tViewController] to set the instance and in 2 it is done directly.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that in first case you do manually release viewController. And it destroyed immediately. In second case object destroyed in the end of the event cycle. 
Sometimes if I perform something memory-consuming in cycle in one function with lots of autoreleased objects - i do create Autorelease pool manualy and drain it every iteration.

From NSAutoreleasePool Class Reference:

***The Application Kit creates an autorelease pool on the main thread at the beginning of every cycle of the event loop, and drains it at the end, thereby releasing any autoreleased objects generated while processing an event.***